# How to speed up the following script to automate the "slapchris.com" hand?

Tags: python, automation, driver, uipath

A friend shared with me a lightweight funny game hosted on [this site](https://slapchris.com), created by Tyler Hamilton. It calculates the speed at which you can drag the image of a hand across the screen. I have a personal high score of 60km/hr, achieved by rotating the phone in landscape mode to get more area and manually dragging the hand.

But I wanted to automate it and get the maximum speed. I wrote this following python script (Pretty novice, I know!) to emulate the drag option.

```
import webbrowser
import time
import pyautogui

webbrowser.open("https://www.slapchris.com")

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.moveTo(392,517)
pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
pyautogui.moveTo(1435,493)
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

But this snippet always gives a maximum (constant) speed of **36 km/hr**. I got this same speed when I tried to automate using UiPath too. Any suggestions on why is it so, or how to optimize this code?  My guess is probably due to the mouse driver.

PS: This is just a fun time pass project. I don't have any polarized opinion on the actual event. #Peace

Comment: You might achieve faster results when using Rust or C instead of Python. The latter is known to be quite slow. Beside that I don't see any option using this GUI approach as you are bound to the implementation and internal processing.

Comment: Is your monitor wider than ~900px?  [The logic](https://slapchris.com/main.js?version=1) used to determine the "velocity" (here, `speedFloat`) is quite odd: `speedFloat = (W < 900 ? velocity * 1.1 : velocity * 0.4) * 1.08;`  So clearly just some synthetic conjured-up number, but if you're trying to compare two different "scores", I'd definitely make sure they both fall into the same "width category", being above or below 900px.  **tl;dr**: resize your browser to less than 900px width and try your script again, you should see your score improve.

Comment: @jedwards That seems like the best way to go. The smaller my browser window the higher my score. I reached 130 km/h btw.